# Unable to kill a process in Perl

Tags: windows, perl, process, exe

I wrote a code to run an exe file as follow:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl     
 use Cwd;                      
 $directory   = 'e:/USER/';
 chdir($directory) or die ; 
 system("Bnc25-Windows.exe -nw");
```

Now I want to write another code to stop it. I wrote:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl     
 use Cwd;                      
 $directory   = 'e:/USER/';
 chdir($directory) or die ; 
 kill Bnc25-Windows.exe ;
```

but it doesn't work and I see in task manager window that the exe file is running.
I don't really know where is the problem. thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Windows. There is no `kill` command in Windows. You can use `taskkill` for this.

Use the `system` function again.

```
system("taskkill /im Bnc25-Windows.exe /f");
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that was all I needed.

Comment: I think this misrepresents the situation. Windows' `kill` command is `taskkill`, but Perl's `kill` operator works fine on Windows.

Comment: ... @Borodin: but the namespace of process IDs that perl's `kill` function can address is not necessarily the same as what `taskkill /PID` can address. For Cygwin perl, at least, they're different.

Answer (score 4):

The [Perl `kill` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) needs (a signal name/number and) the numeric ID of the process you want to kill, not its name.

As general advice, I would *strongly* recommend beginning your code with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

and fixing any errors and warnings they generate.

For example, if you had done that with the code in your question, you would've (after fixing the missing quotes around `Bnc25-Windows.exe` and the missing `my` before the first declaration of `$directory`, so that the code passes `strict` checks) received the following warning:

```
Unrecognized signal name "Bnc25-Windows.exe" at test.pl line 7.
```

This would've told you that `kill` is trying to parse `"Bnc25-Windows.exe"` as a signal name, which would've suggested that there's something wrong with the way you're trying to use it, and would hopefully have led you to look at the documentation (see link above), which both describes the proper way to use the `kill` function in Perl, and also links to the [portability warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#kill) about using it on non-Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

`kill` kills processes by `PID`. You need `killall` to kill a process by executable name. Both are `unix` commands, available on via `cygwin` (which you are, presumably, using).